Multiplying by inverse of sub-matrix knowing inverse of full matrix
We have a real linear operator $M:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. It's invertible and we also know its inverse $M^{-1}$. When represented as real matrices, $M$ and $M^{-1}$ are symmetric. Consider the block matrix representation
$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
B^T & C
\end{array}
\right),
$$
where $A:\mathbb{R}^{m_1} \to \mathbb{R}^{m_1}$, for some $m_1 >0$, $C:\mathbb{R}^{m_2} \to \mathbb{R}^{m_2}$, for some $m_2 >0$, $m_1 + m_2 = n$, and $B$ has appropriate dimensions. Similarly the inverse is represented as
$$
M^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
D & E\\
E^T & F
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where the block dimensions are the same as for the representation of $M$.
The sub-operators $A$, $C$, $D$, and $F$ are invertible.
We would like a formula to evaluate $A^{-1} x$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m_1}$ that only involves elementary operations (no inverses) using $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ or $F$.
I know this question is very similar, but its answer requires to multiply by $F^{-1}$. Browsing around this site I found a reference to this paper, which develops good formulas. I wonder if there is a smart way to manipulate for example equations (4.1) and (4.2) of that paper (its PDF is open access) to get a formula to multiply by $A^{-1}$.
If it's not possible, I'm also interested in any approximate or iterative approach that may work here. This arises in a Levenberg–Marquardt iteration for conic convex optimization. My current practical solution is to simply apply conjugate gradient on $A$, not using at all the knowledge of $M^{-1}$. Anything smarter than that would be an improvement. Thanks!

By any chance, is $m_2$ significantly smaller than $m_1$?

@BenGrossmann unfortunately no; if so I guess it would be better to apply CG on the smaller system.
